# Angular, error de inicializador

Tags: angular, typescript

tengo un error raro que me va a costar explicar espero que me entiendan...

Estoy aprendiendo angular y la relacion entre componentes, estoy llamando un arreglo de objetos de otro componente para que me anden las funciones que tengo declaradas mas abajo que son de suma y resta de un input *(Este input lo estoy haciendo componente para poder reutilizarlo, pero no me están andando los parametros que tengo en el componente HTML, por error de que cuando hago el gamers: Gamers; me salta...)*el error: **La propiedad "gamers" no tiene inicializador y no está asignada de forma definitiva en el constructor**

Probe poniendo ! y editando el ts.json pero me soluciona el error de Gamers: gamers, pero no me soluciona lo de los parametros en HTML.

Mil disculpas mi forma de explicar, me resulta complicadísimo decirlo en palabras.

**Estoy guiándome de un video de un profesor de mi facultad que hace exactamente lo mismo pero a el si le funciona.**

Les dejo mis codigos:

COMPONENTE DE TS DEL INPUT

````
import { GamersAboutComponent } from '../gamers-about/gamers-about.component';
import { Gamers } from '../gamers-tandil/gamers';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-number',
  templateUrl: './input-number.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-number.component.scss']
})
export class InputNumberComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
 gamers: Gamers ;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
//FUNCION DE TS, QUE AUMENTA LA CANTIDAD
MasCantidad(gamers: Gamers): void {
  if(gamers.Cantidad < gamers.Stock)
  gamers.Cantidad++;
  
  }
  
  MenosCantidad(gamers: Gamers): void {
  if (gamers.Cantidad >0)
    gamers.Cantidad--;
    
    }
    
}

COMPONENTE HTML DEL INPUT: 
``` <div> <td><button class="btn btn-success" (click)="MenosCantidad(gamer)">-</button><input size=40 style="width:30px" type=»number» [(ngModel)]="gamer.Cantidad"><button class="btn btn-success"(click)="MasCantidad(gamer)">+</button></td></div> ```




COMPONENTE DONDE TENGO ALOJADO EL ARREGLO DE OBJETOS Y PRINCIPAL DE LA PAGINA:

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Gamers } from './gamers';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-gamers-tandil',
  templateUrl: './gamers-tandil.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gamers-tandil.component.scss']
})


export class GamersTandilComponent implements OnInit {



gamers: Gamers [] =  [{  
"Nombre": "Teclado Mecanico",
"Marca": "Logitech",
"Precio": 12000,
"Stock": 5,
"Image": "assets/images/auricularlogitech.jpg",
"Oferta": false,
"Cantidad": 0, 

},

{ 
"Nombre": "Mouse Inalambrico",
"Marca": "Razer",
"Precio": 6500,
"Stock": 12,
"Image": "assets/images/mouserazer.jpg",
"Oferta": true,
"Cantidad": 0,

},

{
"Nombre": "Auricular",
"Marca": "SteelSeries",
"Precio": 18000,
"Stock": 19,
"Image": "assets/images/auricularss.jpg",
"Oferta": false,
"Cantidad": 0,
  },

{
"Nombre": "Auricular",
"Marca": "Razer",
"Precio": 28000,
"Stock": 9,
"Image": "assets/images/auricularrazer.jpg",
"Oferta": false,
"Cantidad": 0,
  },
{

"Nombre": "Auricular",
"Marca": "Logitech",
"Precio": 30000,
"Stock": 3,
"Image": "assets/images/auricularlogitech.jpg",
"Oferta": false,
"Cantidad": 0,
  },

 {
"Nombre": "Teclado",
"Marca": "Razer",
"Precio": 38000,
"Stock": 11,
"Image": "assets/images/tecladorazer.jpg",
"Oferta": true,
"Cantidad": 0,  

},

{
"Nombre": "Mouse",
"Marca": "SteelSeries",
"Precio": 10000,
"Stock": 42,
"Image": "assets/images/mousess.jpg",
"Oferta": false,
"Cantidad": 0, 

},

{
"Nombre": "Mouse",
"Marca": "Genius Pro Gamer",
"Precio": 3000,
"Stock": 1,
"Image": "assets/images/mousegenius.jpg",
"Oferta": false,
"Cantidad": 0,


}

];



  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


}
````

Comment: Nadie ni idea? :(

Comment: Hola Jaoco. Es normal que a veces las cosas mas sencillas no salgan, pero vayamos por partes, si puedes compartir tú código en github sería más fácil ayudarte, en el caso  **InputNumberComponent** es el componente hijo?  GamersTandilComponent  el padre, que con un bucle for itera el componente hijo, el componente hijo debería ser @Input() gamers: Gamers, y en html del padre inyectarlo al hijo, si no puedo ver más código, no tengo clara la idea, espero que te sirva,

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos!! Gracias por contestar, te dejo el link del github para que te sea mas sencillo ver el problema!!

Comment: Perdona no veo el link?

Comment: https://github.com/JoaquinPavon/angulartpe ahí esta, perdón jajaja

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y funciona correctamente, pero no está el InputNumberComponent

Comment: Ay dios perdón, el otro día cuando me sucedió me trabe tanto que me olvide de hacer el push al github, perdón por hacerte perder el tiempo... Ahí hice el push y esta todo cargado y actualizado hasta donde lo tengo yo en el git! Gracias por la paciencia..

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido resolver lo que te ocurría, voy a explicarlo lo mejor que pueda, si quieres compartir el correo mañana te lo envío por zip te dejo mi correo programaclases@gmail.com.
Empecemos por el componente **InputNumberComponent**

```
@Input() gamer: Gamers = {
    Image: '',
    Nombre: '',
    Marca: '',
    Precio: 0,
    Stock: 0,
    Oferta: false,
    Cantidad: 0,
  };

  constructor() { }
```

Con el @Input conseguimos que el componente hijo pueda recibir los datos del componente padre.
Ahora con el padre, solo la parte **gamers-tandil.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let gamer of gamers" [ngClass]="{'Oferta':gamer.Oferta}">
            <td><img [src]="gamer.Image" [alt]="gamer.Nombre" width="100" height="100"></td>
            <td>{{gamer.Nombre  | uppercase}}</td>
            <td>{{gamer.Marca}}</td>
            <td>{{gamer.Precio  | currency }}</td>
            <td>{{gamer.Stock}}</td>
           <app-input-number [gamer]="gamer"></app-input-number>
        </tr>
```

Con esto tiene que funcionar, si no es así envíame un email y te lo envío.
Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Juan, gracias por responder! Me podrías enviar el zip por favor? Gracias joacopavon@hotmail.com